# C# Vlc ActiveX Play rtsp stream

Tags: c#, controls, activex, vlc, rtsp

I have found a problem to embed and playing rtsp stream to VLC activex control.
Once i already succeeded but now i cant i dont know why,
Im trying to host at WPF a vlc control but its dont work , Its says like a dll is missing , "Failed to import the ActiveX control" I follow after some solutions i found at good but no one helps...
I already registered it, and tried more things..
Its has a missing dll on the AxAXVLC dll.
And say:

> Error 1   Compiler errors occurred when generating a Windows Forms
>   wrapper for ActiveX control 'AxAXVLC'. Source code saved in xxx
>
> Error 2   'AXVLC.IVLCControl2.VersionInfo_2.get': cannot explicitly call
>   operator or accessor xx\ozjsyoc1.0.cs 986 53

Can some1 Can explain me what can i do with this? So i can embed my vlc control?
Another problem is
After i 've embed the vlc control , How can i stream a RTSP video to the control so its will display me a live video from my IP camera.
they have addTarget(...)
Which i cant active the stream with it..
Thanks for help !

Comment: Have you fixed your RTSP problem? Answer is: look in camera documentation for an URL. Some website like [Camera Connection Database](https://www.ispyconnect.com/sources.aspx) may provide one, but the camera manufacturer will probably be much more complete regarding options etc.

Comment: You addressed 2 problems (ActiveX import, RTSP) in one SO question.  It's better to create two different SO questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in VLC. Fixed in version 2.2.2. You can download nightly build here:
http://nightlies.videolan.org/

Comment: That's worked very good , Thanks you ! 
There is a way I can control the caching time delay? reduce it a little bit? 
the default is 1000 ms 
I want to control it from .NET ofc I guess its by entering options but I cant find out ,  Im using the VLC Plugin V2  ? @druss

Comment: any thing u know about it? :) @druss

Answer (score -2):

I have found a problem to embed and playing rtsp stream to VLC activex control.   WPF a vlc control but its dont work , Its says like a dll is missing , "Failed to import the ActiveX control" I follow after some solutions i found at good but no one helps... I already registered it, and tried more things.. Its has a missing dll on the AxAXVLC dll.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXDwe.png)