# Unable to find axAXVLC plugin in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, libvlc

I am trying to use the ActiveX plugin for VLC player in a windows forms application using c#. I can use the "Choose Items..." menu item to add the VLC plugin to the toolbox, but when trying to add it to a form I get a "Failed to import the ActiveX control. Please ensure it is properly registered." message.

I have already registered the dll using regsvr32, and I think the issue is that visual studio is unable to find a reference to the AxAXVLC dll (it imports the AXVLC dll properly).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having the same issue (in VS2008); it wasn't generating the AxAXVLC DLL. If you're using VLC v2.2.1 (or possibly others) then apparently this was a bug and you need v2.2.2; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30825136/225292).

Following the advice in that answer I downloaded the [latest VLC nightly](http://nightlies.videolan.org/) and integrated it into my project. VS complained a bit but eventually it capitulated.

Btw, if you were using v1 of the ActiveX player, apparently it's not present in this version and you'll have to use v2.

Comment: Thanks! it worked out this way. I don't have enough rep vote this up but thank you very much.